# If a druid uses Wild Shape to turn into a Cranium Rat, and has the Pass Without Trace spell active, do they become effectively untraceable?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape, stealth

The [*pass without trace*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/pass-without-trace) spell description says:

> A veil of shadows and silence radiates from you, masking you and your companions from detection. For the duration, each creature you choose within 30 feet of you (including you) has a +10 bonus to Dexterity (Stealth) checks and **can’t be tracked except by magical means.** A creature that receives this bonus leaves behind no tracks or other traces of its passage.

And one of the [Cranium Rat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cranium-rat)'s abilities says:

> ***Telepathic Shroud***. The cranium rat is immune to any effect that would sense its emotions or read its thoughts, as well as  to all divination spells.

With both of these, does this effectively make a druid that is wild-shaped into a cranium rat untraceable (barring undeniable direct line of sight) until one or the other runs out?

Comment: Related: [Can a druid Wild Shape into a Cranium Rat and use Telepathy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138803/33569)

Answer (score 10):

## Sort of, but not really

While you could not be tracked, you could still be detected by a succesful Perception check.

> The GM decides when circumstances are appropriate for hiding. When you try to hide, make a Dexterity (Stealth) check. Until you are discovered or you stop hiding, that check’s total is contested by the Wisdom (Perception) check of any creature that actively searches for signs of your presence.

Also, while pass without Trace does give you a very strong Stealth bonus, you can only use Stealth while travelling if you assume a slow pace. Otherwise, you could be detected (yet not tracked).

### Other ways to detect you

There are a number of non-divination-spell detection effects on monster traits, class features, and lair actions, some of which are magical in nature.

Comment: I suspect also, that there may be some clever spells out there that would allow a creature to be located (directly or indirectly) that are not divination spells. Could be completely off base though.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose your going to make me look aren't you... :)

Comment: "Make" is such a harsh word. I prefer the term "peer pressure". XD

Comment: @DavidCoffron if there is I'd like to know them too :>

Comment: Wish will allow you to locate a creature. It’s a conjugation spell. There is potentially some debate as to whether or not duplicating the effects of a lower level divination spell using wish turns the caster wish into a divination spell (and thus subject to the limitation). If it does, there is always the “make a different wish option”.

Comment: @illustro interesting point. I made a  [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123367/28591) to discuss this, but it seems to be pretty clear to me that duplicated spells from wish count as whatever the spell's school is.

Comment: There's a ranger class feature that overwrites this ... *you can only use Stealth while travelling if you assume a slow pace* depending upon terrain.

Answer (score 9):

### You can no longer do this

As [yeastgoblin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/81166/yeastgoblin) recently pointed out in their [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208202/23547) to [Can a druid Wild Shape into a Cranium Rat and use Telepathy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138803/63061https:), *Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse* (p. 83) reclassified [Cranium Rats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/2560763-cranium-rat) from Beasts to Aberrations.

Since the Cranium Rat is no longer a Beast, it is no longer a valid form for a wild-shaping druid to assume.

Comment: Another heresy perpetrated by the dev team, who have been lost in a *fog cloud* since a bit before before MP:MotM was published. (+1) ... around Tasha's time.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Eh. Creatures with truly supernatural abilities really shouldn't have been beasts in the first place. "Beasts" generally means "natural, creatures from the real world (possibly the past) and other creatures with similar, purely physical, abilities and animal level intelligence". While technically real world critters are immune to divination spells, that's only because divination doesn't work in the real world. :-)

Comment: That said, I still miss being a Druid in the 2E Dark Sun days, when wild shape was broadly worded enough that truly horrifying stuff that just happened to be "natural" on Dark sun,  like Dune Reapers, was considered a valid wild shape form. Nothing like instantly developing natural armor, high speed, and scythes for arms.