# Is there any way to become a swarm of bats as a PC?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, swarm

Is there any way to transform a PC into a swarm of bats without breaking any of the official rules?

Comment: [Can a Druid Wild Shape into a Swarm or "Giant"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45991), [Can a bunch of druids wild-shape into a creature that can swarm, then form a swarm with other wild-shaped druids?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138817)

Comment: Also related on [Can you take the form of a swarm with the *polymorph* spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185759/can-you-take-the-form-of-a-swarm-with-the-polymorph-spell)

Comment: You could become one bat and use mirror image - not quite what you want though.

Comment: Would becoming a bat and controlling a bunch of bat friends count?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### There are no features that allow you to transform into multiple creatures at the same time.

Wild Shape and *polymorph* are explored in these Q&A:

- [Can a Druid Wild Shape into a Swarm or "Giant"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45991/can-a-druid-wild-shape-into-a-swarm-or-giant)
- [Can you take the form of a swarm with the polymorph spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185759/can-you-take-the-form-of-a-swarm-with-the-polymorph-spell)

The issue is that every feature that allows changing form changes you into a single creature, and a swarm is not a single creature. It is treated as a single creature for the purposes of combat mechanics, but it is still a plurality of creatures. This is the obstruction to using Wild Shape and *polymorph*, and it holds for every other feature that allows you to transform. A single creature cannot become more than a single creature.